# How to draw text inside custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have created custom view to draw a custom speech bubble inside
and I want put some text on custom view. I use **drawTextOnPath** but it doesn't work right, I want the text to appear line by line.

**Custom View - Speech Bubble**

```
Paint paint = new Paint();

paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);      
paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(15) );  
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paint.setDither(true);
paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE,
                                                           Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
Path path = new Path();         
paint.setShadowLayer(4, 2, 2, 0x80000000);
path.moveTo(myPath[0].x, myPath[0].y);
for (int i = 1; i < myPath.length; i++){
    path.lineTo(myPath[i].x, myPath[i].y);                  
}
path.close();
canvas.clipPath(path);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
canvas.save();
paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
canvas.drawTextOnPath(MessageBody, path, 10, 10, paint);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a rectangle in the speech bubble like so

```
Rect rcText;
rcText = new Rect(rcBounds);//rcBounds is y speech bubble rect
canvas.save();
```

Limited the draw area

`canvas.cliprect(rect);`

And draw the text inside the speech bubble like this

```
canvas.drawtext(mytext,rect.left,rect.top,paint);
canvas.restore();
```

Thanks mc_fish.

Comment: If a solution worked for you, instead of writing your own answer and accepting that, accept the answer that helped you and comment on that answer what exactly you did if you did additional work than what was provided in the answer. Rewards the people that helped you (mc_fish in this case).

Comment: I don't remember why I write the new answer and accept it, but I think you may be right, I upvoted mc_fish answer at that time. Thanks for pointing me to this @EmilS.

Answer (score 4):

something like this?

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
canvas.drawPaint(paint);
...
//tell the paint of the new color
paint.setColor(android.R.color.black);
paint.setTextSize(20);
canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, paint);
```

edit:

then why not something like this

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addCircle(width/2, height/2, radius, Path.Direction.CW);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setTextSize(20);
canvas.drawTextOnPath("Some Text", path, 0, 0, paint);
```

edit nr2:

why not add a rect?

```
path.addRect(left, top, right, bottom, Direction.CW);
```

or

```
path.addRect(rect, Direction.CW);
```

Comment: no,if text larger than the view size,all of text not show inside of view

Comment: what is rect here? canvas.drawTextOnPath(MessageBody, rect, 10, 10, paint);

Comment: it's draw circle,my custom view like rectangle

Comment: yeah it was just a poc:) your path probably has bugs did u try to debug?

Comment: yeah,it's work fine to draw speech bubble but i can't draw text inside it.i draw rectangle on my path but it didn't work!

Comment: i use addrect but draw text on border of rect,not inside of rect

Comment: then do What about Paint.getTextBounds() and an if

Comment: i write a func. calculate the size of text and then draw the bubble for the text size,then draw text on it.write in onMeasure.